# How to calculate the difference b/w each element in an numpy array with a shape[0]>2

Tags: python, numpy, diff

Please feel free to let me know whether it is a duplicate question.

From
`in_arr1 = np.array([[2,0], [-6,0], [3,0]])`

How can I get:
`diffInElements = [[5,0]]` ?

I tried `np.diff(in_arr1, axis=0)` but it does not generate what I want.
is there a NumPy function I can use ?

Cheers,

Comment: Why do you expect `[[5, 0]]`? How do you get that result? I don't understand at all.

Comment: Hi Andras, thanks for your reply.
I want to get the difference of element as : 2-(-6)-3 = 5 and 0-0-0 = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to subtract the remaining rows from the first row. The straightforward answer does just that:

```py
>>> arr = np.array([[2, 1], [-6, 3], [3, -4]])
>>> arr[0, :] - arr[1:, :].sum(0)
array([5, 2])
```

There is also, however, a more advanced option making use of the somewhat obscure `reduce()` method of numpy ufuncs:

```
>>> np.subtract.reduce(arr, axis=0)
array([5, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can negate and then sum all but the first value, and then add the first value:

```
diff = (-a[1:]).sum(axis=0) + a[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> diff
array([5, 0])
```